# Toggle Highcharts plotLine with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Good afternoon guys,

Just a very quick one: I was wondering whether it'd be possible to toggle a PlotLine (on/off) without having to remove it and then have to add it from scratch. The reason for this is that I am building my charts from a PHP array and can only define the plotline value once when the chart is loaded.

At the moment when I try to add a plotline from its ID it fails.

```
var hasPlotLine = true 
        $button = $('#button'),
        chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    $button.click(function() {
        if (!hasPlotLine) {
            chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine('hello');
            $button.html('Remove');
        } else {
            chart.yAxis[0].removePlotLine('hello');
            $button.html('5-day average');
        }
        hasPlotLine = !hasPlotLine;
    });
```

Please take a look at my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/3ApbR/

Also: would it be possible to get highcharts to give the last five day average directly? So the average of the last five data points ... and then plot the line for me? This could potentially get me around the issue...

Love you all and thanks for your help.

G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can echo your php into a javascript variable so that you can add it whenever you need.

However, as to your last question, you can easily grab the last 5 data points from the chart, calculate the average, and plot it.

`example`:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/HZ88T/

relevant code:

```
...
},function(chart) {
    var lData = chart.series[0].data.slice(-5);
    var points = [];
    $.each(lData,function(i, point) {
        points.push(point.y);
    });
    var avg = mean(points);
    var options = {
        value:avg,
        width:1,
        color:'#c00',
        label: {
            align:'right',
            textAlign:'left',
            y: 2,
            text: '5 Day Avg: '+ avg,
            style: {
                fontSize:'9px'
            }
        }
    };
    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotBand(options);
});
//----------------------------------------
function mean(arr) {
    if(typeof arr != 'undefined') {
        var sum = 0;
        $.each(arr,function(i,v) {
            sum += v;
        });
        return sum / arr.length;
    }
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: jlbriggs this looks extremely promising. However for some reason the jsfiddle does not bring up the chart? Hope all is well and thank you.

Comment: link works fine for me.  does the link not bring you to jsfiddle.net? or does the chart not load once you get there?  I tried in firefox and chrome and had no problems...

Comment: jlbriggs, hope all is well. Your code is awesome. It works perfectly for standard highcharts ... but I have failed to adapt it to a stockchart. What do I need to do to get it to work? Am guessing some manipulation is needed because the data is now in [x, y] format as opposed to straight x1,x2,x3 format ...?

Comment: the [x,y] format should not be a problem.  You may have to adjust to account for which series you are trying to work with.  Can you set up a fiddle with an example of your stock chart?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load your php array into a js array initially, then use this variable wherever/whenever you need it?

```
$(function () {
    //create attribute array
    var attr = {
                id: 'hello',
                value: 60,
                width: 1,
                color: 'red',
                dashStyle: 'dash',
                label: {
                    text: '5-day average',
                    align: 'left',
                    y: 10,
                    x: 0
                }
            }
 . . .
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ApbR/2/